# Have US deficits been cut in half since Obama came into office?

Tags: united-states, politics

Recently in [this interview with CNBC](http://www.npr.org/blogs/thetwo-way/2013/10/02/228568286/obama-says-hes-exasperated-by-the-gop) (at 00:00:39), President Obama said "Deficits are coming down; they have been cut in half since I came into office."

Is this true? What statistic is he referring to? Is this more or less a red herring, referring to the extraordinarily large deficits that were temporarily run for things like TARP, etc.?

Answer (score 8):

The [Congressional Budget Office](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congressional_Budget_Office) defines the [federal budget deficits](http://www.cbo.gov/sites/default/files/cbofiles/attachments/budgetinfographic.pdf) (pdf) as when spending exceeds revenues for the fiscal year ([October 1st through September 30th](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiscal_year#United_States)) so it is reasonable to assume that this what [President Obama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama) is referring to when he maid that claim. Additionally, since the deficit is defined solely on the basis of the receipts vs. outlays, programs such as the [Troubled Asset Relief Program (TARP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troubled_Asset_Relief_Program) are included in the official figures.

According to the Monthly Treasury Statement for [September 2013](http://www.fms.treas.gov/mts/mts0913.pdf) (pdf) there was a $680 billion deficit for Fiscal Year 2013 through September 30, 2013. According to the [Office of Management and Budget](http://www.whitehouse.gov/omb) [Historical Tables](http://www.whitehouse.gov/omb/budget/historicals), the following are the total receipts, outlays, and deficits for 2008 through 2012 ([source](http://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/default/files/omb/budget/fy2014/assets/hist01z1.xls), xls) in [nominal dollars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_versus_nominal_value_%28economics%29):

```
Year    Receipts    Outlays     Surplus or Deficit (-)
2008    2,523,991   2,982,544   -458,553
2009    2,104,989   3,517,677   -1,412,688
2010    2,162,706   3,457,079   -1,294,373
2011    2,303,466   3,603,059   -1,299,593
2012    2,450,164   3,537,127   -1,086,963
```

Using the Fiscal Year 2009 deficit of $1,412 billion that means that as of August 2013 the Fiscal Year 2013 reduction of $680 billion is **accurate** on the hard numbers and is about a 52% reduction.

If we adjust these values for inflation by using an [inflation calculator](http://www.bls.gov/data/inflation_calculator.htm) then we find that $680 billion in 2013 dollars is the same about $623 billion in 2009 dollars. This represents about a 56% reduction in the deficit when compared to it in 2009 which means that the statement is also **accurate** using inflation adjusted figures.

Another way of looking at the deficit is as a percentage of the [gross domestic product (GDP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_domestic_product) which has also been done by President Obama and was [examined by FactCheck.org](http://www.factcheck.org/2013/08/deficits-falling-from-way-up/),

> In fact, although the White House didn’t cite it, the newly released
>   mid-year projection from the White House Office of Management and
>   Budget for the 2013 fiscal year shows that due to rising revenues, the
>   2013 deficit is now projected to be $759 billion — $214 billion lower
>   than the $973 billion deficit projected in the original budget. As a
>   percentage of GDP, the 2013 deficit is now projected to equal 4.7
>   percent. The nonpartisan Congressional Budget Office projects an even
>   lower 2013 deficit of $642 billion, or 4 percent of GDP. That’s still
>   above the level in 2008 (or any year since 1992), but it’s
>   substantially lower than 2009. (Even if those projections pan out,
>   however, Obama’s talking point wouldn’t be correct.)

where the deficit as a percentage of the GDP was -10.10% [on December 31, 2009](http://www.multpl.com/u-s-federal-deficit-percent/table) which would make this claim **accurate** but still dependent upon the final Fiscal Year 2013 data.

Comment: The deficit in 2009 doesn't appear to be drastically higher than in the years that follow. I assume that the majority of the difference between 2008 levels is due to lower government receipts, rather than a result of TARP and the stimulus?

Comment: Do you know if the table you exhibit is in inflation adjusted dollars or in raw dollars?

Comment: I think a 47% reduction qualifies as "cut in half". I would rate the statement as true, or at least "mostly true", but certainly not "not accurate"

Comment: In 2013 dollars, the 2009 deficit was roughly 1,540,000, so the current deficit is less than half that.

Comment: I just ran your numbers through a standard inflation adjuster.

Comment: There was a trillion dollar "one time" expense in 2009 if you eliminate that then the numbers are not in the Big O's favor.

Comment: @Chad I *really* don't want to drag politics into this answer.

Comment: @Chad: What trillion dollar expense are you talking about?  TARP?  The [Treasury](http://www.treasury.gov/initiatives/financial-stability/reports/Pages/TARP-Tracker.aspx) reports that total expenditures under TARP (2008-present) were about $421 billion.  It looks to me like only about $300 billion net was spent in FY 2009.  Moreover, since TARP repayments have now exceeded outlays, if you don't count TARP expenditures you should also remove the corresponding receipts, which would make the deficits in 2010 and later larger.

Comment: @NateEldredge and the GM and Chrysler bailouts.  And that they have been repaid does not mean that they did not count against 2009 when they happend.  An arguement could be made that they are artifically lowering the current deficit numbers

Comment: @Chad: By the [numbers](http://useconomy.about.com/od/criticalssues/a/auto_bailout.htm) I found, the automaker bailouts totaled $34 billion, of which $24 billion was included as part of TARP.  It seems we are still a long way from $1 trillion.  Do you have a source for that number?

Comment: @Chad: Regarding paybacks, from the Treasury chart I linked earlier, the vast majority of TARP repayments were made in FY 2010-2012.   I don't think the effect on the FY 2013 numbers would be so large.

Comment: @NateEldredge - Yes so those repayments are reducing the deficit but it is being applied to the numbers from 2010-2012 instead of 2009 where they were applied. 34 billion is what was left from GM after the writedown and the first repayment.  GM was over 140B and Chrystler was something like 20B

Comment: The claim that the deficit decreased from FY09 to FY13 is accurate enough. However, his claim was _since he came into office_. The majority of FY09 was while he was already in office and he authorized several hundred billions dollars of spending in FY09, including ARRA and the omnibus spending bill passed shortly after he took office, along with several smaller, but still significant bills. So, his actual claim is not accurate. (Also, as previously noted, comparing to FY09 is already misleading due to TARP, Freddie/Fannie bailouts, and unusually low revenue.)